# How do I retrieve the same HTML from the inspect menu when the data served is XML?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using Python's `request` module to scrape this website: http://reports.ieso.ca/public/Adequacy2/PUB_Adequacy2_20200114.xml

```
import requests

def get_info(date=None):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    }

    response = requests.get('http://reports.ieso.ca/public/Adequacy2/PUB_Adequacy2_20200114.xml', headers=headers,verify=False)
    print(response.text)
    return response

get_info()
```

Now it returns XML, which I understand. But the HTML structure I see when I inspect that website is different, and much better in it's structure.

Is there a way to get that data with requests instead of the XML data? Or other alternatives?

Comment: I think the website has some JS code turning that API response (xml) into the html you’re seeing with your browser.

Comment: Yea I see some `xsl` tags in the code actually, would that be it? Is there no way to retrieve the final result I see in the browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: _But the HTML structure I see when I inspect that website is different, and much better in it's structure._ In what way is it better? Usually direct access to the data is far more desirable than having parse a bunch of a HTML. The XML seems just fine to me.

Comment: Really? It's arranged in tables with rows in the HTML. Seems much more intuitive

Answer (score -1):

I think beautiful soup might do what you are asking.

Install beautiful soup

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

"soup" object hopefully parses to what you are expecting

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Yes this came to mind, I wasn't sure because the source seems to be only XML. This or Selenium, but if it's possible in these why not in `requests`? What are they doing different?

Comment: ah sorry wasn't sure if this would work. Like you said it was first thing that came to mind.

Comment: I actually found another URL by inspecting: http://reports.ieso.ca/docrefs/stylesheet/Adequacy2_HTML_t1-3.xsl But it gives my some xsl markup? I have no idea where the browser gets the HTML

Comment: BeautifulSoup is just an HTML parser, why would it make a difference?

Comment: @AMC Because html is not the same as xml

Comment: @Maxqueue Right, but if the data returned by the request isn’t what we need, then parsing that same data won’t change much.